# Ajax-loader.gif ends once page loads

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now.  I have OpenCart 1.5.2.1 installed, and during the checkout phase I have several steps that must complete in the background.  While this is happening, I'm trying to displaying a simple ajax-loader.gif, and I want it to disappear once the page is done processing.  At the moment, the ajax-loader.gif isn't showing...

Here's my javascript:

```
  var el = $("#confirm .checkout-heading").addClass("loading");
  $.ajax({
      url: 'checkout/checkout.php',
      success: function(data) {},
      failure: function() {},
      complete: function() {
          el.removeClass("loading");
      }
  });
```

Stylesheet:

```
#confirm .checkout-heading {
    background: #fff;
}
#confirm .checkout-heading.loading {
    background-image: url('../image/ajax-loader.gif');
    background-position: 98% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Page:

```
  <div class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <?php echo $breadcrumb['separator']; ?><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
  <div class="checkout">
    <div id="checkout">
      <div class="checkout-heading"><?php echo $text_checkout_option; ?></div>
      <div class="checkout-content"></div>
    </div>
    <?php if (!$logged) { ?>
    <div id="payment-address">
      <div class="checkout-heading"><span><?php echo $text_checkout_account; ?></span></div>
      <div class="checkout-content"></div>
    </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <div id="payment-address">
      <div class="checkout-heading"><span><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_address; ?></span></div>
      <div class="checkout-content"></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
    <div id="shipping-address">
      <div class="checkout-heading"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?></div>
      <div class="checkout-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="shipping-method">
      <div class="checkout-heading"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?></div>
      <div class="checkout-content"></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="payment-method">
      <div class="checkout-heading"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?></div>
      <div class="checkout-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="confirm">
      <div class="checkout-heading">Confirm Purchase</div>
      <div class="checkout-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three possible reasons:

1. You are trying to get element before DOM is ready (use $(document).ready));
2. Ajax execution is too fast so you cant observe loader.
3. You've got troubles with css/image. To test it get rid of javascript and see if it works on static content (add class "loading" manually).

In the following example i've postponed execution of ajax for 2 secs :

http://jsfiddle.net/webdevel/Dd3B7/1/

Comment: thanks.  I have confirmed that the issue seems to stem from #3.  When I drop the class `.loading` and set the loader image as the background for `.checkout-heading`, the image appears but does not go away once the page has loaded, whereas when I add the class `.loading` manually, nothing happens, no image.  Additionally, when I add the `(use $(document).ready));` function, I simply get a "0" on the page.